# How to show if $X_1$ and $X_2$ both have MGFs (marginally), then the vector $(X_1, X_2)$ has an MGF as well?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X_1,X_2$ are jointly distributed r.v.s, not necessarily independent or identically distributed.

I want to show that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ both have MGFs (marginally), then the vector $(X_1, X_2)$ has an MGF.

I am wondering if the final form is:

$$
M_{(X_1, X_2)}(t) = M_{X_1}(t)M_{X_2}(t)
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X_1$ has mgf in interval $|t|< t_1$ and $X_2$ hasd mgf in interval $|t|<t_2$.

Now by Cauchy Schwarz Inequality, $[M_{(X,Y)}(r_1,r_2)]^2=(E(e^{r_1X_1+r_2X_2}))^2\leq E(e^{2r_1X_1})E(e^{2r_2X_2})$. Hence the mgf of $(X_1,X_2)$ exists in $|r_1|<t_1/2$ and $|r_2|<t_2/2$

Comment: I don't quite understand your proof, why does the inequality show it? Don't we need an equality?

Comment: There is an interval in which the joint mgf exists.